# When this structure is allocated, how much memory is wasted?

Tags: memory, memory-management, rust

I'm building an index tree based on a bplus tree in Rust and have so far used a definition for parent nodes as:

```
struct Parent<T : std::fmt::Debug> {
    subtree_count : [usize; Arity],
    children      : [*mut ParentOrLeaf<T>; Arity],
    used          : usize, 
}
```

On my 64 bit computer with Arity=8 that works out to a total memory requirement of 136 bytes.  I'm using `std::alloc::Layout::new` and `std::alloc::alloc` to allocate this structure.  But I'm worried that being just slightly larger than a power of two (136 > 128) that the malloc library will end up allocating 256 bytes for this data structure instead of just 136.  Since this is a container type, wasting half the memory allocated is unacceptable.

`std::alloc::Layout::new::<Parent<T>>().align()` reports a layout of 8 as expected.

How much memory will this structure actually take up when it is allocated?

If so much memory is wasted, I could change `subtree_count : [usize; Arity]` to `subtree_count : [usize; Arity-1]`, which would make the total memory 128.  Then redo all of the optimized logic of my library to handle the change.  But before I do, I want to make sure that is actually necessary.

Comment: I would assume that data alignment is enforced by default, so the padding of 136 bytes up to 256 is highly probable

Comment: Maybe as a workaround you could remove `used` field and rely on a corresponding value from `subtree_count` from parent?

Comment: This isn't a question of *alignment*, as that term is normally used. On a typical 64 bit machine the alignment of `Parent` is just 8, not 128. It's instead a question of how the allocator manages space.

Comment: @AlexLarionov The nature of bplus index trees is that used is that used is necessary but that you could determine the last subtree_count using what the parent says the total subtree count for this vertex is.

Comment: This will certainly depend on the allocator you use, but I doubt it will end up allocating a lot of excess memory. An allocated memory chunk will always contain some metadata in addition to your payload, e.g. the size of the chunk. I seem to remember that glibc will always allocate multiples of 8 bytes, so you wouldn't actually waste any memory with your data structure.

Comment: See https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals for some details on the glibc `malloc()` implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the size is 136 this means that a contiguous allocation of many structs in an array or a vector will use exactly 136 bytes for each struct.

When it comes to individually allocating some structs, the amount of wasted space only depends on the underlying `malloc()` strategy, but is not a property of the allocated type.

For example, a quick and dirty adaptation of your example on my stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu platform gives this :

```
size 136
align 8
arr delta1 136
arr delta2 136
box delta1 144
box delta2 144
```

Of course there is no guaranty that the three allocated structs are near to each other, but in this specific case they are, and the *wasted* (not really wasted, but used by the allocator itself) space is 8 bytes.

```rust
struct ParentOrLeaf<T: std::fmt::Debug> {
    value: Option<T>,
}

const Arity: usize = 8;

struct Parent<T: std::fmt::Debug> {
    subtree_count: [usize; Arity],
    children: [*mut ParentOrLeaf<T>; Arity],
    used: usize,
}

fn main() {
    type P = Parent<i32>;
    let l = std::alloc::Layout::new::<P>();
    println!("size {}", l.size());
    println!("align {}", l.align());
    let ptr: *mut ParentOrLeaf<i32> = std::ptr::null_mut();
    let arr = [
        P {
            subtree_count: [0; Arity],
            children: [ptr; Arity],
            used: 0,
        },
        P {
            subtree_count: [0; Arity],
            children: [ptr; Arity],
            used: 0,
        },
        P {
            subtree_count: [0; Arity],
            children: [ptr; Arity],
            used: 0,
        },
    ];
    let a0 = &arr[0] as *const P as usize;
    let a1 = &arr[1] as *const P as usize;
    let a2 = &arr[2] as *const P as usize;
    println!("arr delta1 {}", a1 - a0);
    println!("arr delta2 {}", a2 - a1);
    let p0 = Box::new(P {
        subtree_count: [0; Arity],
        children: [ptr; Arity],
        used: 0,
    });
    let p1 = Box::new(P {
        subtree_count: [0; Arity],
        children: [ptr; Arity],
        used: 0,
    });
    let p2 = Box::new(P {
        subtree_count: [0; Arity],
        children: [ptr; Arity],
        used: 0,
    });
    let a0 = p0.as_ref() as *const P as usize;
    let a1 = p1.as_ref() as *const P as usize;
    let a2 = p2.as_ref() as *const P as usize;
    println!("box delta1 {}", a1 - a0);
    println!("box delta2 {}", a2 - a1);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, so it seems it is consuming memory up to 144 bytes, so 8 bytes of wasted space so 6% of space wasted.

Comment: The 8 bytes aren't "wasted" – they are metadata used by the allocator, and there is no way to avoid them.

Comment: @DanielV yes but, as stated before the code, only on this specific case and on my platform. there is no guaranty.

Comment: I mean, you _could_ write your own allocator just for objects of this exact size, in which case you possibly could make do with less metadata, but when using a general-purpose allocator it's unlikely you will be able to do any better.

Comment: @SvenMarnach yes of course, I meant « from the point of view of the application », not the system.

Comment: So I ran a version of this on my computer and got the same box results.  And messing with the arity, it seems it is a +8 byte header , not rounding.  This is good news, I don't have to change anything.